# How to make a math mode non-Ord macro?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, tex-core

I want to make a new macro that'll act like its own character. Specifically, I want `\macro` to expand to `a\kern0.5em b`, but still act as a `Rel` character (i.e. `1\macro1` would have a small space around the `a  b` similar to how the `=` in `1=1` has a space).

I've tried `\def\macro{\mathrel{a\kern0.5em b}}`, but a problem arises when it's used as an exponent: `x^\macro` expands to `x^\mathrel{ ... }`, which TeX doesn't like and throws an error. I know I could just enclose it like `x^{\macro}`, but I'm looking for a way where you wouldn't have to put braces around it each time. I also know that whether it's a `Rel` atom or not doesn't matter when used as a lone exponent, but I want it to work in all situations, exponent or not.

Is there any way to make a macro (with a `{`group`}` like `{a\kern0.5em b}`) that's not treated like an `Ord` character *and* that works when used as an exponent or subscript?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow, but best practice is to employ `x^{\test}` rather than `x^\test`.

Comment: I know it would work in its own group like you said, but is there any way to get it to work with or without the braces?

Comment: `\def\macro{\bgroup\mathrel{a\kern0.5em b}\egroup}` seems to work.

Comment: @corporal - with your definition, `\macro` is of type `math-ord`, not `math-rel`.

Comment: @mico - OK, thanks for letting me know, I've read the answer that it's not possible, I'll revisit the TeXbook.

Comment: If `x^t` works, good. But the correct syntax is `x^{t}`, even if `t` is a single token like in your example. The same happens with `\notin`, for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is not possible.  As soon as you enclose something in a brace group it becomes an Ord atom.   The TeXbook Chapter 26 “Summary of
Math Mode” is very specific about this:

> `{`<math mode material>`}`. A character token of category 1, or a control sequence like `\bgroup` that has been `\let` equal to such a character token, causes TeX to start a new level of grouping and also to begin work on a new math list. When such a group ends—with ‘`}`’—TeX uses the resulting math list as the nucleus of a new Ord atom that is appended to the current list. If the resulting math list is a single Acc atom, however (i.e., an accented quantity), that atom itself is appended.

For the syntax `x^\macro` to work the contents of `\macro` have to be a math field.

> <superscript><math field>. A <superscript> command is an explicit or implicit character token of category 7.  If the current list does not end with an atom, a new Ord atom with all fields empty is appended; thus the current list will end with an atom, in all cases.  The superscript field of this atom should be empty; it is made nonempty by changing it to the result of the specified <math field>.

A math field however, is either a single symbol or a brace group

> A <math field> is used to specify the nucleus, superscript, or subscript of an atom. When a <math field> is a <math symbol>, the *f* and *a* numbers of that symbol go into the atomic field. Otherwise the <math field> begins with a ‘`{`’, which causes TeX to enter a new level of grouping and to begin a new math list; the ensuing <math mode material> is terminated by a ‘`}`’, at which point the group ends and the resulting math list goes into the atomic field. If the math list turns out to be simply a single Ord atom without subscripts or superscripts, or an Acc whose nucleus is an Ord, the enclosing braces are effectively removed.

---

You could however simply exploit the fact, that the spacing around a Rel atom in scriptstyle is zero and use the following definition

```
\def\macro{{{}\mathrel{a\kern0.5em b}{}}}

$x \macro y$

$z^{x \macro y}$

$z^\macro$ % Brrr...

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This is I suspect the best answer there is (unless you make ^ math active and read its argument as a macro argument) but you should probably note that `\macro` doesn't act like a true `\mathrel` as it always adds space compare `$=$` and `$\macro$` (which is like `${}={}$`)